Как на https сайте передать http ссылку через JS?
Разрабатываю сайт, работает на Django (Daphne + обратный прокси Apache2 с 443 настройкой).
URL моего сайта: https://my.site. Пытаюсь вставить видео в HTML5 Video. Через JS в .src передаю ссылку: http://url.site, в логах браузера вижу, что в плеер прилетает ссылка: https://url.site.
Можно ли этот момент как-то обойти?

Нельзя, иначе в https просто не было бы смысла

Понимаю, думал есть, что-то вроде replace в момент загрузки в браузере... в общем надеялся на чудо :)
